# Get a non-recursive list of local directories (containing templates) in Ansible

Tags: ansible, glob, subdirectory

I have a bunch of directories containing similar template files in an ansible role.
Something like:

```
/ansible/
└── roles
    └── webserver
        ├── tasks
        │   └── main.yml
        └── templates
            └── sites
                ├── bar
                │   ├── index.html
                │   ├── script.js
                │   ├── style.css
                │   └── webapp.conf
                ├── baz
                │   ├── index.html
                │   ├── script.js
                │   ├── style.css
                │   └── webapp.conf
                └── foo
                    ├── index.html
                    ├── script.js
                    ├── style.css
                    └── webapp.conf
```

In the task, I want to list the directories (`bar`, `baz`, `foo`, plus whatever new ones I create there) and apply template actions to their files.

I've tried using `with_fileglob` but it can't list directories (only files, it ignores directories).

```yaml
- name: Template index.html
   template:
     src: "sites/{{item}}/index.html"
     dest: "/var/www/{{item}}/index.html"
   with_fileglob: "templates/sites/*"
```

There is also a [regression](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/17136) such that it can't even find the files with a glob on the directory.

```yaml
- name: Template index.html
   template:
     src: "sites/{{item}}"
     dest: "/var/www/{{item}}/index.html"
   with_fileglob: "templates/sites/*/index.html"
```

I've tried `find`, but I can't get it to work on the local templates directory (it seems to find things on the host.)

I've tried `filetree`

```yaml
- name: Template index.html
   template:
     src: "sites/{{item.path}}"
     dest: "/var/www/{{item.path}}/index.html"
   with_filetree: "templates/sites/"
   when: item.state == 'directory'
```

but it:

- Is recursive (even if I use a `when` to limit it to directories, it returns sub-directories)
- Prints annoying messages about all the things it skips

Is there a way to get a list of all my sites in my local template directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `filetree` and make it less verbose and up to your need, you can use it as a lookup, and not as a `with_*` loop.

This way you can pre-filter it with the help of the [`selectattr`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr) and [`rejectattr`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.rejectattr) filters:

For example:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.path }}"
  loop: >-
    {{
      lookup('community.general.filetree', 'templates/sites')
        | selectattr('state', '==', 'directory')
        | rejectattr('path', 'contains', '/')
    }}
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.path }}"
```

In this task:

- `selectattr('state', '==', 'directory')` will ensure you are only listing directories
- `rejectattr('path', 'contains', '/')` will reject path containing a `/`, so effectively excluding subdirectories
- `loop_control` and its parameter `label: "{{ item.path }}"` will make the loop less verbose on complex dictionaries

---

Or your can use JMESPath, as your partially used it indeed, but the filtering can be part of the query:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: >-
    {{
      lookup('community.general.filetree', 'templates/sites')
        | json_query('[?state == `directory` && !contains(path, `/`)].path')
    }}
```

---

Given the file strucure:

```
.
└── templates
    └── sites
        ├── bar
        │   ├── baz
        │   └── index.html
        └── foo
            └── index.html
```

Where `baz` is a subdirectory, the two tasks above would both yield:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item=bar) => 
  msg: bar
ok: [localhost] => (item=foo) => 
  msg: foo
```

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell using the `find` module you cited earlier

In `roles/webserver/vars/main.yml`

```yaml
---
available_sites: "{{ find_sites_subdirs.files | d([]) 
  | map(attribute='path') | map('basename') }}"
```

*Note: `d` is an alias to `default` and is there only to avoid errors in case you use the var before running `find` below (in which case it will be an empty list)*

Then in `roles/webserver/tasks/main.yml`

```yaml
---
- name: Find sites subdirs
  ansible.builtin.find:
    paths:
      - "{{ role_path }}/templates/sites"
    file_type: directory
    recurse: false
  register: find_sites_subdirs
  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: true

- name: Template index.html
  ansible.builtin.template:
    src: "sites/{{ item }}/index.html"
    dest: "/var/www/{{ item }}/index.html"
  loop: "{{ available_sites }}"
```

Comment: `delegate_to: localhost` is what makes it run locally?

Comment: yes => https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_delegation.html. And `run_once` is what makes it run for a single host in your host loop. The register will then be pushed with the same value to all targeted hosts facts.

Comment: Does that work if `localhost` isn't one of your registered hosts?

Comment: `localhost` is an implicit host that is always accessible

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to use `filetree` with some pipes to filter it down to just the base directories.

```yaml
- name: Template index.html
  template:
    src: "sites/{{item}}"
    dest: "/var/www/{{item}}/index.html"
  with: >-
    {{
      lookup('filetree', 'templates/sites')
      | selectattr('state', 'eq', 'directory')
      | rejectattr('path', 'contains', '/')
      | map(attribute='path')
      | list
    }}
```

- `lookup('filetree', 'templates/sites')` does the recursive scan of the directory
- `selectattr('state', 'eq', 'directory')` filters out the files
- `rejectattr('path', 'contains', '/')` filters out sub-directories
- `map(attribute='path')` returns just the list of `item.path` rather than full objects with lots of extraneous fields.
- `list` converts it to a list that can be used with `with:`

To use this list multiple times, it is more efficient to put it in a variable.  It can go in `roles/webserver/vars/main.yml` like:

```yaml
my_sites: >-
  {{
    lookup('filetree', 'templates/sites')
    | selectattr('state', 'eq', 'directory')
    | rejectattr('path', 'contains', '/')
    | map(attribute='path')
    | list
  }}
```

Then the template can just use `with: "{{my_sites}}"`

Comment: There is no regression in the fileglob lookup. This is explained in a [comment in the issue you linked](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/17136#issuecomment-241012104) which also gives the solution you have implemented above.

Comment: The regression is the case of `with_fileglob: "templates/sites/*/index.html"` which returned a list of files in Ansible 2.1.3, but does not using 2.2.0.  See https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/17136#issuecomment-258616881